# z-index not working in safari and phone screen

Tags: html, css, safari, z-index

color disappear with z-index in safari and phone screen

When I added background-color and z-index: -1 to .tabordion section label:before,
.tabordion section label:after, The color of .tabordion section label disapear

```css
.tabordion {
  color: #333;
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
  position: relative;
  width: 85%;
}
.tabordion input[name="sections"] {
  position: absolute;
        top: 50px;
}

.tabordion section {
  display: block;
}

.tabordion section label {
        line-height: 1.1;
        display: block;
    padding: 21px 0px;
    border: none;
    font-size: 1.2rem;
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #2b6a83;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 -2px 0 0 transparent inset;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  width: 320px;
  z-index: 99999 !important;
    margin-bottom: 10px;

}

.tabordion section article {
    display: none;
    left: 400px;
    min-width: 300px;
    padding: 30px 30px 20px 21px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
}
.tabordion section article h2{
    color: #2b6a83;
}
.tabordion section article:after {
  bottom: 0;
  content: "";
  display: block;
  left:-229px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 220px;
  z-index:1;
}
.tabordion input[name=sections]:checked+label {
    background: #2b6a83db;
    color: white;
    border: 1px solid #2b6a83;
    border-right: 1px solid #ffffff;
}
.tabordion input[name="sections"]:checked ~ article {
  display: block;
}
.tabordion section label:before,
.tabordion section label:after {
  position: absolute;
     background-color: #2b6a83;
   z-index: -10000 !important;
        color: white;
  content: '';
  height: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  border-right: 3px solid #2b6a83;
  transition: all 1s ease-out;
}
.tabordion section label:before {
  top: -1px;
  border-top: 1px solid #2b6a83;
  transform-origin: left top;
  transform: perspective(100px) rotateX(30deg);
}
.tabordion section label:after {
  bottom: -0px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #2b6a83;
  transform-origin: left bottom;
  transform: perspective(100px) rotateX(-30deg);
}
.btContentHolder .resim{
        height: 150px;
}
article .col-md-6{
        padding: 20px;
} 
article h2{
        padding-left: 20px;
}
article hr{
         display: block; height: 1px;
    border: 0; border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
    margin: 1em 0; padding: 0;
}
.tabordion section label:hover {
    border: #2b6a83;
    color: #e9736a;
    font-weight: 800
}
```

```html
<div class="tabordion"><section id="section1"><input id="option1" checked="checked" name="sections" type="radio" />
<label for="option1">Family Caregivers</label><article>
<div class="ro">
<h2>Family Caregivers</h2>
<div class="col-md-6"><img class="resim alignnone wp-image-21889" src="http://www.bigheartshomecare.ca/wp-content/uploads/2021/04/Screen-Shot-2021-04-06-at-1.44.41-PM.png" alt="" /></div>
<div class="col-md-6">
<h3>Caregiving Strategies Handbook</h3>
<h4>Providing Care and Support for a Senior Living with Frailty</h4>
<a href="http://www.bigheartshomecare.ca/wp-content/uploads/2021/04/Caregiver-Strategies-Handbook.pdf" target="_blank" rel="noopener">Read More..</a>

</div>
</div>

<hr />

<div class="ro">
<div class="col-md-6"><img class="resim alignnone wp-image-21903" src="http://www.bigheartshomecare.ca/wp-content/uploads/2021/04/Coronavirus-CDC-645x645-1.jpg" alt="" /></div>
<div class="col-md-6">
<h3>A Guide for Caregivers in Contact with COVID-19</h3>
<h4>Guide for caregivers and household members of those with
COVID-19</h4>
<a href="http://www.bigheartshomecare.ca/wp-content/uploads/2021/04/A-Guide-for-Caregivers-in-Contact-with-COVID-19.pdf" target="_blank" rel="noopener">Read More..</a>

</div>
</div>

<hr />

<div class="ro">
<div class="col-md-6"><img class="resim alignnone wp-image-21907" src="http://www.bigheartshomecare.ca/wp-content/uploads/2021/04/Screen-Shot-2021-04-06-at-2.19.26-PM.png" alt="" /></div>
<div class="col-md-6">
<h3>Practical Information for Family Caregivers</h3>
<h4>Practical information for caregivers of older adults</h4>
<a href="http://www.bigheartshomecare.ca/wp-content/uploads/2021/04/Practical-Information-for-Family-Caregivers.pdf" target="_blank" rel="noopener">Read More..</a>

</div>
</div>
</article></section><section id="section2"><input id="option2" name="sections" type="radio" /><label for="option2">Alzheimer’s &amp; Dementia</label><article>
<h2>Alzheimer’s and Dementia</h2>
<div class="ro">
<div class="col-md-6"><img class="resim alignnone wp-image-21936" src="http://www.bigheartshomecare.ca/wp-content/uploads/2021/04/Screen-Shot-2021-04-06-at-10.26.30-PM.png" alt="" /></div>
<div class="col-md-6">
<h3>Caring for Someone with Alzheimer's or Dementia</h3>
<h4>A HANDBOOK FOR CARE</h4>
<a href="http://www.bigheartshomecare.ca/wp-content/uploads/2021/04/Caring-for-Someone-with-Alzheimers-or-Dementia.pdf" target="_blank" rel="noopener">Read More..</a>

</div>
</div>

<hr />

<div class="ro">
<div class="col-md-6"><img class="resim alignnone wp-image-21938" src="http://www.bigheartshomecare.ca/wp-content/uploads/2021/04/Screen-Shot-2021-04-06-at-10.29.23-PM.png" alt="" /></div>
<div class="col-md-6">
<h3>Dementia: A Guide for Caregivers</h3>
<h4>Communicating about dementia with healthcare providers</h4>
<a href="http://www.bigheartshomecare.ca/wp-content/uploads/2021/04/Dementia-A-Guide-for-Caregivers.pdf" target="_blank" rel="noopener">Read More..</a>

</div>
</div>

<hr />

<div class="ro">
<div class="col-md-6"><img class="resim alignnone wp-image-21940" src="http://www.bigheartshomecare.ca/wp-content/uploads/2021/04/Screen-Shot-2021-04-06-at-10.32.29-PM.png" alt="" /></div>
<div class="col-md-6">
<h3>Dementia in Canada Statistics</h3>
<h4>DEMENTIA IN CANADA, INCLUDING ALZHEIMER’S DISEASE</h4>
<a href="http://www.bigheartshomecare.ca/wp-content/uploads/2021/04/Dementia-in-Canada-Statistics.pdf" target="_blank" rel="noopener">Dementia in Canada Statistics</a>

</div>
</div>
</article></section><section id="section3"><input id="option3" name="sections" type="radio" /><label for="option3">COPD</label><article>
<h2>Chronic Obstructive Pulmonary Disease (COPD)</h2>
<div class="ro">
<div class="col-md-6"><img class="resim alignnone wp-image-21955" src="http://www.bigheartshomecare.ca/wp-content/uploads/2021/04/Screen-Shot-2021-04-06-at-11.02.21-PM.png" alt="" /></div>
<div class="col-md-6">
<h3>COPD Handbook</h3>
<h4>Signs and Symptoms of Chronic Obstructive Pulmonary Disease</h4>
<a href="http://www.bigheartshomecare.ca/wp-content/uploads/2021/04/COPD-Handbook.pdf" target="_blank" rel="noopener">Read More..</a>

</div>
</div>
</article></section><section id="section4"><input id="option4" name="sections" type="radio" /><label for="option4">Stroke</label><article>
<h2>Stroke</h2>
<div class="ro">
<div class="col-md-6"><img class="resim alignnone wp-image-21961" src="http://www.bigheartshomecare.ca/wp-content/uploads/2021/04/iStock-1168179082.jpg" alt="" /></div>
<div class="col-md-6">
<h3>A Guide for Stroke Survivors and Families</h3>
<h4>A GUIDE FOR STROKE SURVIVORS, FAMILIES, &amp; CAREGIVERS</h4>
<a href="http://www.bigheartshomecare.ca/wp-content/uploads/2021/04/A-Guide-for-Stroke-Survivors-and-Families.pdf" target="_blank" rel="noopener">Read More..</a>

</div>
</div>
</article></section><section id="section5"><input id="option5" name="sections" type="radio" /><label for="option5">Palliative Care</label><article>
<h2>Palliative Care</h2>
<div class="ro">
<div class="col-md-6"><img class="resim alignnone wp-image-21961" src="http://www.bigheartshomecare.ca/wp-content/uploads/2021/04/Screen-Shot-2021-04-06-at-11.12.32-PM.png" alt="" /></div>
<div class="col-md-6">
<h3>A Caregiver's Guide to the Dying Process</h3>
<h4>“Dying is not primarily a medical condition, but a personally experienced, lived condition.”</h4>
<a href="http://www.bigheartshomecare.ca/wp-content/uploads/2021/04/A-Caregivers-Guide-to-the-Dying-Process.pdf" target="_blank" rel="noopener">Read More..</a>

</div>
</div>

<hr />

<div class="ro">
<div class="col-md-6"><img class="alignnone size-full wp-image-21963" src="http://www.bigheartshomecare.ca/wp-content/uploads/2021/04/Screen-Shot-2021-04-06-at-11.15.12-PM.png" alt="" width="755" height="467" /></div>
<div class="col-md-6">
<h3>Guiding Family Caregivers through End of Life Care</h3>
<h4>Why Do Family Caregivers Needs To Be Guided To Take Care Of Themselves?</h4>
<a href="http://www.bigheartshomecare.ca/wp-content/uploads/2021/04/Guiding-Family-Caregivers-through-End-of-Life-Care.pdf" target="_blank" rel="noopener">Read More..</a>

</div>
</div>
</article></section><section id="section6"><input id="option6" name="sections" type="radio" /><label for="option6">Respite Care</label><article>
<h2>Respite Care</h2>
<div class="ro">
<div class="col-md-6"><img class="resim alignnone wp-image-21967" src="http://www.bigheartshomecare.ca/wp-content/uploads/2021/04/Screen-Shot-2021-04-06-at-11.22.29-PM.png" alt="" /></div>
<div class="col-md-6">
<h3>Respite Care Guide</h3>
<h4>Finding What’s Best for You. Respite refers to a short time of rest or relief.</h4>
<a href="http://www.bigheartshomecare.ca/wp-content/uploads/2021/04/Respite-Care-Guide.pdf" target="_blank" rel="noopener">Read More..</a>

</div>
</div>
</article></section><section id="section7"><input id="option7" name="sections" type="radio" /><label for="option7">Postpartum Care</label><article>
<h2>Postpartum Care</h2>
<div class="ro">
<div class="col-md-6"><img class="resim alignnone wp-image-21970" src="http://www.bigheartshomecare.ca/wp-content/uploads/2021/04/Screen-Shot-2021-04-06-at-11.28.19-PM.png" alt="" /></div>
<div class="col-md-6">
<h3>Your Guide to Postpartum Care</h3>
<h4>The first 6 weeks after birth is known as the postpartum period.</h4>
<a href="http://www.bigheartshomecare.ca/wp-content/uploads/2021/04/Your-Guide-to-Postpartum-Care.pdf" target="_blank" rel="noopener">Read More..</a>

</div>
</div>

<hr />

<div class="ro">
<div class="col-md-6"><img class="resim alignnone wp-image-21973" src="http://www.bigheartshomecare.ca/wp-content/uploads/2021/04/Screen-Shot-2021-04-06-at-11.33.15-PM.png" alt="" /></div>
<div class="col-md-6">
<h3>Postpartum Care in Canada</h3>
<h4>The postpartum period is a significant time for the mother, baby, partner, and family.</h4>
<a href="http://www.bigheartshomecare.ca/wp-content/uploads/2021/04/Postpartum-Care-in-Canada.pdf" target="_blank" rel="noopener">Read More..</a>

</div>
</div>
</article></section><section id="section8"><input id="option8" name="sections" type="radio" /><label for="option8">Hospital Discharge</label><article>
<h2>Hospital Discharge</h2>
<div class="ro">
<div class="col-md-6"><img class="resim alignnone wp-image-18146" src="http://www.bigheartshomecare.ca/wp-content/uploads/2021/02/bh-blog-hospital-discharge-planning.jpg" alt="hospital discharge planning" /></div>
<div class="col-md-6">
<h3>Hospital_to_Home</h3>
<h4>In the Hospital: Planning for Discharge, Know Who Is on the Discharge Team</h4>
<a href="http://www.bigheartshomecare.ca/wp-content/uploads/2021/04/Hospital_to_Home-1.pdf" target="_blank" rel="noopener">Read More..</a>

</div>
</div>
</article></section></div>
```

Here picture to add more explanation [image]

Answer (score 0):

Do not take a negative z-index, make it positive and give the div above it a bigger z-index

Edit: this may solve your issue with safari `-webkit-transform:translate3d(0,0,0);`

Comment: Can you please add what you said to my example

Comment: I just edited my answer. try putting that snippit of code in to the applicable divider